# What is the difference between "Should Be True ${list} == ['a', 'b', 'c']" and "Should Be True $list == ['a', 'b', 'c']"?

Tags: robotframework

Consider the following code in built-in-library-tests.robot:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Use "Create List"
   #  The returned list can be assigned both to ${scalar} and @{list} variables
   @{list} =   Create List     a   b   c
   Should Be True      ${list} == ['a', 'b', 'c']    # (1)
   Should Be True      $list == ['a', 'b', 'c']      # (2)
```

To me, (1) and (2) must differ in execution, even though they both pass.

**In (1)**, `${list}` is replaced with string representation of the `@list` (i.e. `['a', 'b', 'c']` ), the resulting the expression **as a string**:

> ['a', 'b', 'c'] == ['a', 'b', 'c']

(1) is like  running eval("['a', 'b', 'c'] == ['a', 'b', 'c']") on python console. Is this correct?

**(2) is NOT like running eval("['a', 'b', 'c'] == ['a', 'b', 'c']") on python console**; First the `$list` in evaluation namespace refers to `@{list}` object from Robot.

$list == **['a', 'b', 'c']**

How is the list on the right side (i.e. **['a', 'b', 'c']** above) handled? Is it parsed as a string and based on the parsing result a new list object is placed to the right hand side of == operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that robot will convert `${list}` to a string before evaluating the expression, but will make the variable directly accessible to python with `$list`.

This is described in the [Evaluating Expressions](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluating%20expressions) section of the Builtin library documentation:

> When a variable is used in the expressing [sic] using the normal ${variable} syntax, its value is replaces[sic] before the expression is evaluated. This means that the value used in the expression will be the string representation of the variable value, not the variable value itself. This is not a problem with numbers and other objects that have a string representation that can be evaluated directly, but with other objects the behavior depends on the string representation. Most importantly, strings must always be quoted, and if they can contain newlines, they must be triple quote

...

> Starting from Robot Framework 2.9, variables themselves are automatically available in the evaluation namespace. They can be accessed using special variable syntax without the curly braces like $variable. These variables should never be quoted, and in fact they are not even replaced inside strings.

You wrote *"To me, (1) and (2) must differ in execution, even though they both pass."*.

They both pass due to the fact that the string representation of the list looks like a list to python. This is called out in the first paragraph I quoted above:

> ... This is not a problem with numbers and other objects that have a string representation that can be evaluated directly, but with other objects the behavior depends on the string representation...

To see an example where they do not have the same behavior, use a variable that contains a string.

Example:

```
*** Variables ***
${test}  hello, world

*** Test Cases ***
Passing Example
    should be true  $test=='hello, world'

Failing Example
    # this will fail with the following error:
    # Evaluating expression 'hello, world=='hello, world'' failed: NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
    should be true  ${test}=='hello, world'  # fails
```

Later you edited the question to ask this:

*"How is the list on the right side (i.e. ['a', 'b', 'c'] above) handled? Is it parsed as a string and based on the parsing result a new list object is placed to the right hand side of == operator?"*

In short, yes.

When robot is given `$list == ['a', 'b', 'c']`, it is initially a string that looks literally like `$list == ['a', 'b', 'c']`. Since the right hand side has no variables, that is exaclty what gets passed to `eval`, and eval sees a string that looks like a list, so it creates a new list before doing the comparison.

For the value on the left, in effect robot simply removes the `$` while making the variable `list` available, so it is the same as if you called `eval` like this: `eval("list == ['a', 'b', 'c']")`.

Comment: #2 is still unclear, i made my questions on #2 a bit more clear by editing the questions on #1 and #2.

Comment: @HKN: I've updated my answer with an additional explanation.